# Set "custom" withErrors without Request->validation in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to display an error in a form, but it cannot be checked via validation.

**Blade**

```
    <form action="/githubuser" methode="GET">
        <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('CustomeError') }}</div>
        <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="GitHub Username ..." value="John12341234">
        @if($errors->has('userName'))
            <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('userName') }}</div>
        @endif            
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
```

**The Problem** is that I start an api call after validation. and if I don't get "GitHubUser" as a response, I want to print an error message in the blade. GitHub user not found.

**Controller**

```php
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = ['userName' => 'required'];
        $validator = \Validator::make($request->input(), $rules);
        
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
        }
        
        $data = $this->gitHubUserService->getUserData($request->input('userName'));
        /* User on Github not Found **/
        if (! $data) {
            // >>> THE LINE BELOW IS MY PROBLEM! <<<
            return view('form')->withErrors($validator);
        }

        // ....
     }
```

At the end of the day I want the line `<div class="error">{{ $errors->first('CustomeError') }}</div>` to be displayed in the blade.

**Is this possible?** Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use a custom Request class?

Comment: @mohammadmahdibaleghsefat hi! Can you explain me how to use and how will solve my problem? thank you!

Comment: So basically you want to inject html into error message right ?

Comment: Read this. [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) It will redirect and give you all errors.

Comment: @mohammadmahdibaleghsefat Thanks for your comment and link to the documentation. It  is also good aproach.

Answer (score 1):

The original validator is not getting any error, because there are none. So, just add a new error to the `errors` inside of your if body before returning form view:

```php
if(! $data){
    $validator->errors()->add('customError', 'Github User not found!');
    return view('form')->withErrors($validator);
}
```

Comment: @FarhanLbnWahid Thanks. Exactly what i want.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help 

Comment: I'm glade that you help me 

Comment: yes i will do that.

Comment: would you please accept my answer? maybe you forgot @MaikLowrey